# GetFingerprintCount() needs to return number of fingerprint in the system pool but returning only 1 when 4 fingerprints are present

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, fingerprint

```
import ctypes
import msvcrt
from ctypes import Structure, c_ulong, POINTER



# Constants
WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT = 0x00000008
WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM = 0x00000001
WINBIO_FLAG_DEFAULT = 0x00000000
WINBIO_ID_TYPE_SID = 3
WINBIO_E_BAD_CAPTURE = 0x80098003
WINBIO_E_NO_MATCH = 0x80098005
WINBIO_I_MORE_DATA = 0x40098002


# Load the winbio.dll library
lib = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\Windows\System32\winbio.dll")

# Define WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL structure
class WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("RejectDetailSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
        # Add other fields if needed
    ]

# Function prototypes
lib.WinBioOpenSession.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_uint32,                      # Factor
    ctypes.c_uint32,                      # PoolType
    ctypes.c_uint32,                      # Access
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p),       # Array of unit IDs
    ctypes.c_ulong,                       # Unit count
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)),  # Database ID
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))  # Session handle
]

# Function prototypes
lib.WinBioEnumBiometricUnits.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_uint32,  # Biometric type
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)),  # Array of unit schema
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong),  # Count of unit schema
]

lib.WinBioCloseSession.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_void_p  # Session handle
]

lib.WinBioLocateSensor.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # Session handle
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)  # Unit ID
]

lib.WinBioEnrollBegin.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # Session handle
    ctypes.c_uint32,  # Finger to create template for
    ctypes.c_void_p   # Biometric unit ID
]

lib.WinBioEnrollCapture.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # Session handle
    ctypes.POINTER(WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL)  # Failure information
]

lib.WinBioEnrollCommit.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # Session handle
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p),  # WINBIO_IDENTITY object for the user
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_bool)  # Is this a new template
]

lib.WinBioEnrollDiscard.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_void_p  # Session handle
]

def GetFingerprintCount():
    unitSchema = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)()
    unitCount = ctypes.c_ulong()

    # Enumerate the biometric units of the specified type (fingerprint)
    hr = lib.WinBioEnumBiometricUnits(WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT, ctypes.byref(unitSchema), ctypes.byref(unitCount))
    if hr != 0:
        print("WinBioEnumBiometricUnits failed. hr = 0x%x" % hr)
        return 0

    return unitCount.value


def EnrollSysPool(discardEnrollment, subFactor):
    hr = 0
    identity = ctypes.c_void_p()
    sessionHandle = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)()  # Updated argument type
    unitId = ctypes.c_void_p()  # Updated variable type
    rejectDetail = WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL()
    isNewTemplate = ctypes.c_bool(True) 

    # Connect to the system pool.
    hr = lib.WinBioOpenSession(WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,  # Service provider
                            WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,  # Pool type
                            WINBIO_FLAG_DEFAULT,  # Configuration and access
                            None,  # Array of biometric unit IDs
                            0,  # Count of biometric unit IDs
                            None,  # Database ID
                            # ctypes.byref(sessionHandle)  # [out] Session handle
                            sessionHandle)
    
    if hr != 0:
        print("WinBioOpenSession failed. hr = 0x%x" % hr)
        return hr

    # Locate a sensor.
    print("\nSwipe your finger on the sensor...")
    hr = lib.WinBioLocateSensor(sessionHandle, ctypes.byref(unitId))
    if hr != 0:
        print("WinBioLocateSensor failed. hr = 0x%x" % hr)
        return hr

    # Begin the enrollment sequence.
    print("\nStarting enrollment sequence...")
    hr = lib.WinBioEnrollBegin(sessionHandle, subFactor, unitId)
    if hr != 0:
        print("WinBioEnrollBegin failed. hr = 0x%x" % hr)
        return hr

    # Capture enrollment information by swiping the sensor with
    # the finger identified by the subFactor argument in the
    # WinBioEnrollBegin function.
    swipeCount = 1  
    rejectDetail = WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL()
    while True:
        print("Swipe the sensor to capture %s sample." % ("the first" if swipeCount == 1 else "another"))
        hr = lib.WinBioEnrollCapture(sessionHandle, ctypes.byref(rejectDetail))
        print("Sample %d captured from unit number %d." % (swipeCount, ctypes.cast(unitId, ctypes.c_void_p).value))
        print("Thisis WINBIO_I_MORE_DATA value:",WINBIO_I_MORE_DATA)

        if hr == 0x90001:
            print("More data required.")
            swipeCount += 1
            continue
        elif hr != 0:
            if hr == WINBIO_E_BAD_CAPTURE:
                print("Error: Bad capture; reason: %d" % rejectDetail)
                continue
            else:
                print("WinBioEnrollCapture failed. hr = 0x%x" % hr)
                return hr
        else:
            print("Template completed.")
            break

        

    # Discard the enrollment if the appropriate flag is set.
    # Commit the enrollment if it is not discarded.
    if discardEnrollment:
        print("\nDiscarding enrollment...\n")
        hr = lib.WinBioEnrollDiscard(sessionHandle)
        if hr != 0:
            print("WinBioEnrollDiscard failed. hr = 0x%x" % hr)
    else:
        print("\nCommitting enrollment...")
        hr = lib.WinBioEnrollCommit(sessionHandle, ctypes.byref(identity), ctypes.byref(isNewTemplate))
        if hr != 0:
            error_msg = ctypes.create_string_buffer(256)  # Buffer to hold the error message
            lib.WinBioHresultToString(hr, error_msg, 256)
            print("WinBioEnrollCommit failed. hr = 0x%x. Error message: %s" % (hr, error_msg.value))


    # Close the session handle
    # lib.WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle)
    lib.WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle.contents)  # Dereference the pointer
    print("Press any key to continue...")
    msvcrt.getch()
    return hr



def main():
    discardEnrollment = False  # Set to True if you want to discard the enrollment, False otherwise
    subFactor = 1  # Set the appropriate finger value, e.g., 0 for the first finger

    hr = EnrollSysPool(discardEnrollment, subFactor)

    if hr == 0:
        print("Enrollment successful.")
    else:
        print("Enrollment failed. hr = 0x%x" % hr)

    fingerprintCount = GetFingerprintCount()
    print("Number of fingerprints in the system pool:", fingerprintCount)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

GetFingerprintCount() function is returning value 1 when I have 4 fingerprint in the systempool 2 created with enroll function and 2 by system UI i am expecting it to give the correct value. and i am also not able to verify the the fingerprint stored in the pool its allowing me to login with all 4 fingers but when i try to verify the using python code it only verifies through the 1st fingerprint i stored using system ui and for rest it doesnot verify if possible can anyone help with verify functionality as well or provide links to refer for verify.

Answer (score 0):

So regarding your first part of "why `GetFingerprintCount` doesn't work" - it's because `WinBioEnumBiometricUnits` returns you, as it says, the number of units and not fingerprints taken. A biometric unit is the software component that correlates to a physical sensor. If you have one sensor you'll have only one biometric unit. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd401512(v=vs.85)).

What you want is to use `WinBioEnumEnrollments`, which will give you all the enrollments done for a specific identity (every user can have a biometric identity). To count on your own identity, simply follow the example in the function's [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbioenumenrollments). It will use `WinBioIdentify` which will actually check your identity with the sensor.
Counting other users feels to me a bit out of scope and can be discussed separately if it's a use case.

Regarding the second part of "how to actually verify it works" - you may simply use `WinBioIdentify` and pass your new added finger. Then you can check that it returns your identity and even that the subfactor is correct.